# Build SqlCredential in C# Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm creating a Web Service using C#. I've a SQL Database in a host, so I'm building a `SqlConnection` instance in order to be able to execute queries.

But to use `SqlConnection` you need a `SqlCredential`, which needs of `SecureString` in order to be initialized (or to assign a password anyway).

The problem is, that `SecureString` can be easily obtained from a password textbox, but it's not so easy when you **want to build it without it** (since it's a webservice, so it doesn't have any GUI).

The only available method I've found is `SecureString.AppendChar()`, so I would have to build the `SecureString` **by using a loop over my original password string**, in order to add its chars to it, which seems quite weird for me.

Does exist any other approach to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, people will simply create a Sql Connection with the connection string set in the Web.config.

You can pass the connection string into the constructor of your SqlConnection, like so:

(in the Web.Config)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="nameOfConnectionString" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you'd access it like this:

```
var connectionString = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nameOfConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

For more information on the varying types of connections and formats, you can google the info, but [SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) usually lists the layouts.

Comment: I've seen this, and readed that it's unsecure, but anyway I'm going to do this xD Thanks

Comment: Try looking at this article about securing the connection strings (note that internal apps will not have the web.config served up to the public so it's not as unsafe as one might believe):  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178372(v=vs.140).aspx